# Proving that quotient subgroups of congruent subgroups of modular group are finite.

Tags: number-theory, analytic-number-theory, quotient-group

I am trying exercises of Tom M Apostol Modular Functions and Dirichlet series in number Theory Chapter 2 and I cannot think about this problem ( Problem 2.12) .

> Its image has many definitions which are useful in question but doubt is only in question 12 .

Adding Image -- 
[image]

[image]

> I can only think that $\Gamma^n$ will be equal to Identity matrix modulo n here. 
>   But I don't know if that can be used to prove the statement.

Can somebody please help. 
Edit 1 - Can somebody please give hint for this question also.

> Question 13 Prove that The index of $\Gamma^n$ in $\Gamma$ is the number of equivalence classes of matrices modulo n.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $\Gamma=\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})$,the ring homomorphism $$
\mathbb{Z}\to\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z},\;x\mapsto [x]
$$induces a group homomorphism$$
\varphi\colon\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})\to\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}),\;\begin{pmatrix}
a & b\\ c & d
\end{pmatrix}\mapsto\begin{pmatrix}
[a] & [b]\\ [c] & [d]
\end{pmatrix}.
$$By isomorphism theorems, we have$$
\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z})/\ker(\varphi)\cong \operatorname{im}(\varphi)\leq\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z}).
$$But you can easily determine the kernel of the map:$$
\ker(\varphi)=\{A=\begin{pmatrix}a & b\\ c& d\end{pmatrix}\in\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}):a\equiv d\equiv 1\mod n,\;b\equiv c\equiv 0\mod n\}=\Gamma^{(n)}
$$Since the image is a subgroup of $\operatorname{SL}_2(\mathbb{Z}/n\mathbb{Z})$ and this is finite, we have that the quotient is finite aswell.

Comment: thanks a lot. I have another question which I mentioned by editing this question. Can you please take a look if you have some time to spare

Comment: It is not at all obvious that the reduction mapping ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf Z) \rightarrow {\rm SL}_2(\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)$ is surjective! That issue is not necessary to see the quotient group of ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf Z)$ modulo the kernel is finite, but it is needed to explain the isomorphism in your answer.

Comment: Thank you for the comment, KCd! I only remember that the map $\varphi$ is surjective, but as you have said it is not obvious to prove. I adjusted my answer.

Comment: @larskei I think the question I asked in Edit ie Question no. 13 is true by definition of index  . Am I right?

Comment: ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf Z) \rightarrow {\rm SL}_2(\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)$ is surjective because the latter is generated by $\pmatrix{1&1\\0&1},\pmatrix{0&1\\-1&0},\pmatrix{a&0\\0&a^{-1}}$, 

only the last one is a problem, take $ac\equiv 1\bmod N^2$ then $ac-1 = (bN)(dN)$ and $\pmatrix{a&bN\\dN&c}\in {\rm SL}_2(\mathbf Z)$

Comment: @reuns  can you please give some hint for question no. 13  . Is my argument which is mentioned in comments right?

Comment: Well your question 13 is exactly the same as surjectivity of ${\rm SL}_2(\mathbf Z) \rightarrow {\rm SL}_2(\mathbf Z/n\mathbf Z)$